# Avoid spent money with waiting time in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have web crawlers running (python+requests) in AWS Lambda that use solving captcha as third party service. This service (solving captcha) spends 3 minutes (average) so a good portion of the value of AWS bill come from waiting time. Is there any way to avoid paying for these waiting times?

I tried to use Redis to keep session and kill running Lambda to another one to assume it is getting from Redis again. But it didn't worked.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: i dont believe lambda is the right option here...consider a docker container or like a t2.micro.

Comment: I think the ec2 its more expensive it doesnt ?

Comment: EC2 may be better as you won't need a very big one.  How many requests are you doing per minute?

Comment: There are 700 requests to peak and 120 to lowest case.

Comment: @CláudioR.Mendonca ec2 is more expensive in certain contexts...for your reference, EC2 may be cheaper. spot instances will drive that cost even lower

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll try it !

Comment: If the website is using a Captcha, then they clearly do not want you scraping their content. We do not encourage activities that violate a website's Terms and Conditions. I suggest you investigate whether that site has an API for accessing content rather than scraping their data.